# Filter JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to only return 1's from this array but I am having trouble figuring out whats wrong with my code.

```
let arr = [[1],[1,2],[3],[1,2],[4],[1,2],[1]];
let ok = arr.filter((x) => {
  if(x.length > 1){
    return x.filter((y) => {
      return y == 1;
    })
  }else{
    return x == 1;
  }
})
console.log(ok);
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example of what you expect the output to be?

Comment: `return x == 1` - you are comparing reference with a number here

Comment: You should return a boolean value from `.filter`, but you are returning the result of the inner `.filter`, which is an array.

Comment: @pwolaq which will actually work, as `[1] == 1` is `"1" == 1` which is `1 == 1` which is `true`

Comment: please add the wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `x.filter` returns a new filtered array. But that is not really used as it is passed to the outer filter, which will then take that to decide wether to filter the outer one. So actually it seems as the outer `filter` should actually `map`:

```
let ok = arr.map(inner => inner.filter(el => el === 1));
```

You also do not need that `if` statement as the code works nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas gave a very good answer above, though I'm not sure this is what was asked. I have a feeling :) that you need only arrays which were exactly `[1]` in the original array `arr`. If so:

```
const arr = [[1],[1,2],[3],[1,2],[4],[1,2],[1]];
const ok = arr.filter(el => el.length === 1 && el[0] === 1) // [[1], [1]]
```